# How to find line error in init.m file?

Tags: programming

I have been changing my init.m user file.  It runs fine, but I do get this error below.  What does it mean by line 55?  What constitutes a line?  Are lines separated by "," or ";" or both?  Or is it something else?

I'd like to be able to count down to the line but I don't know what a line consists of so I don't know what to count.  I'm sorry if this is dumb question.  Can someone clarify for me?

> Syntax::com: Warning: comma encountered with no adjacent expression.
>   The
>        expression will be treated as Null.  (line 55 of
>        "/Users/michaelmccain/Library/Mathematica/Kernel/init.m").

Also, is there a good method for finding bugs in my Mathematica programs?  From my limited experience in C++, I do remember there was a way to isolate errors by evaluating the code in steps with a button.  Does Mathematica have this functionality?

Comment: Lines are just that - lines, as you would encounter them in your average editor (delimited by CR). Expressions or compound expressions are something else, a line can contain several of those. There are several threads on debugging around, please use the search function.

Comment: Thank you.  That was a dumb question.  Since a line is followed by a CR, then I realized its just one line of code.  I turned on the Cell Labels and found it easily.  Thank you!

Comment: Not a dumb question. Debugging is still somewhat inconvenient compared to other systems. Actually, could self-answer and help future visitors with your solution (not sure if this is a duplicate, but seems like a problem others might run into as well).

Answer (score 2):

Cell labels puts the line number to the left of each line of code.  All I had to do was turn it on.  Thank you Yves Klett.